# Formatting a Date String into a Date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to format a string Date `"14/06/2019 12:52"` using moment library in order to manipulate a Date object and not a string.

I tried using moment library but didn't succeed to have a Date object

`const myDate = moment('14-06-2019 12:52')`

the const `myDate` is not of type Date.

Comment: moment('14-06-2019 12:52:00') Speficy the seconds too. Maybe that'll work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the format also

```
const myDate = moment('14-06-2019 12:52', 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm');
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. Actually i tried const myDate = moment('14-06-2019 12:52', 'DD-MM-YYYY mm:ss').toDate() and it works fine

Comment: glad it helped, btw its hour so use hh:mm :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `moment().toDate();`

Refer here for more info http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/

Comment: actually it didn't worked. i got today's date on the output. I want to have a specific date and not today's date when i type moment().toDate('14-06-2015 12:52') for exemple

Comment: That's because you are using it the wrong way. :) Use Date parameter inside moment() not in toDate function: `const myDate = moment('14-06-2019 12:52', 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm').toDate();`